# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, exception

i am trying to extract value from web site and inserting value in my db  when i am going to   insert data  in my db i am getting   exeception

Exception is :  Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

here is  my code

```
public class ScrapCom {
    Statement st = null;
    Connection cn = null;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        int j = 0;
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.getDefault());
        String sDate = "27/03/2014";
        String url = "http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx";
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Jo");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys(sDate);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"));
        String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
        // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
        htmlTableText = htmlTableText.replace("S.No.DistrictMarketPrice", "");
        htmlTableText = htmlTableText.replaceAll("\\s(\\d+\\s[A-Z])", "\n$1");
        htmlTableText = htmlTableText.replaceAll("(?=(.*?[ ]){4,}).*?[\n\r]", "");
        System.out.println(htmlTableText);
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(htmlTableText);
        while (str.hasMoreElements()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                String no = str.nextElement().toString();
                String city = str.nextElement().toString();
                String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();
                String price = str.nextElement().toString();
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mandi", "root", "");
                //insert them into the database
                PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("insert into commoditywise  values(?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, no);
                ps.setString(2, city);
                ps.setString(3, mandi);
                ps.setString(4, price);
                j = ps.executeUpdate();
                cn.close();
            }
        }
        if (j == 1) {
            System.out.println("data inserted");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not inserted");
        }
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

updated exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextElement(StringTokenizer.java:407)
    at Getdata1.main(Getdata1.java:48)
Java Result: 1
```

What am I missing here?

How can i remove this exception

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the exception stacktrace to your question.

Comment: sorry i did not get ur mean

Comment: A mean all exception's data that is printed in the console when you run your program, not only the single line `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`, which you specified.

Comment: @MockerTim i updated all line which i am getting at the time of exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is not the db insert. You are using `StringTokenizer.nextElement()` without testig if a next element is available.

```
while (str.hasMoreElements()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         String no = str.nextElement().toString();
         String city = str.nextElement().toString();
         String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();
         String price = str.nextElement().toString();
```

If you do multiple `nextElement()` calls in a row you should first check if the expected token count is available by using `StringTokenizer.countTokens()`

> public int countTokens()
>
> Calculates the number of times that this tokenizer's nextToken method can be called > before it generates an exception. The current position is not advanced.
>
> Returns:
>      the number of tokens remaining in the string using the current delimiter set.
>   See Also:
>       nextToken()

Comment: +1 It seems the OP do not need niether while, nor for loop here. The OP just need to check if the `str` has next element - before each `nextElement()` call.